# build and run android project having a subproject in command line using ant debug

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to buil an android project from command line. My android project has a sub project inside my main android project. When I run the ant debug command it showing error in building classes as not found the library classes from the subproject. So I think the sub project is not included correctly, we need to execute some command for that.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I got the answer from android official doc

android update lib-project --target 3 --path ZBarScanner-master/ZBarScannerLibrary
android update project --name android_app --path . --library ZBarScanner-master/ZBarScannerLibrary

First we need to update the library project and then update the main project. Both should be create before doing the update.

then do

ant clean
ant debug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer from Android official doc:

```
android update lib-project --target 3 --path ZBarScanner-master/ZBarScannerLibrary 
android update project --name android_app --path . --library ZBarScanner-master/ZBarScannerLibrary
```

First we need to update the library project and then update the main project. Both should be created before doing the update.  Then do:

```
ant clean 
ant debug
```

Comment: For those that got an error because of '--target 3',  you can skip it and it will work. Or use 'android list targets' to see valid targets you have on your machine