# Android with Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: android, maven, ant, build-process, android-maven-plugin

For the past 3 weeks I've played heavily with Android Maven build process. For the most part I find it a much better experience than Eclipse but have a few questions I'd like answered:

- Is there a way to make Eclipse work with APKLIB files without importing the project into Eclipse?
- Using Maven is there a way to push the APK to the device without uninstalling the application?  Using mvn android:deploy uninstalls the APK and installs a new one.
- I've yet to get the Android JavaDoc to work well in IntelliJ, any solutions?
- Does IntelliJ work well with the NDK?

I'm open to any tips in the best build process for the platform as it will be what I use moving forward.  Should I go Ant or Maven?

Comment: regarding Ant vs Maven : I maintain both build system (only because Ant is the official build tool). I suggest you this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441204/android-command-line-tool-ant-debug-in-project-with-libraries/15447207#15447207

Answer (score 1):

1. APKLIB support in Eclipse is still not fully there. Use m2eclipse and m2eandroid and maybe help with patches for m2eandroid.
2. mvn android:deploy can install an apk to the device (or all attached devices). mvn android:run can start it. undeploy and redeploy work as well.
3. the maven android sdk deployer can also deploy the source and it should hook up fine with intellij and the maven integration
4. NDK and Intellij - not for writing code but the build process via Maven will work just fine also in Intellij..

Last but not least.. you should definitely NOT go ant. Either Maven or use the new, upcoming Gradle build. Don't waste time on the old (and soon to be deprecated) Ant build and all its problems.